# jquery draggable does not want to work in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, draggable, jsfiddle

I've prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWRhr/11/) with the code.

when "small buble" is pressed there is a big and small bubble, (change the name to sth else and another bubble will show up). The problem is that it does not want to be draggable in chrome and opera. Under IE it works ok, I can drag both bubbles (they move together). Under chrome or opera only the big one is draggable, the other is not.

the desired structure of elemetns is

```
<div id="bubble-someUserName" class="bubbles-user" >
     <div class="bubbles-view"></div>
     <div class="bubbles-view"></div>
     <div class="bubbles-view"></div>
</div>
```

and I'm setting

```
$('.bubbles-user').draggable();
```

What am I missing here then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

There are a few issues:

1) In the JSFiddle you are using

```
MainContainer().find('#bubbles-' + userName) ...
```

Which is looking for an ID, not a class. The second bubble doesn't have an id, and it also doesn't have the `bubbles-user` class you want to be looking for.

2) Your elements are not nested in the way you are expecting.

The smaller bubbles are child elements of the larger bubble NOT the container. This is probably because of your animation requirements.

3) Even once you clear those, it won't work. Still not sure why but I think it has to do with item #2 and the fact that the click handling isn't bubbling as expected. You may need to use a [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in there somewhere to attach handlers to newly created elements

Comment: it is a desired efect, the #bubbles-someUserName are unique bubbles for users. They have their ID-s. The small bubbles are representing activities connected with the user (the big bubble). When dragging they should drag together. The problem is that in IE i can drag both (and they move together) and in chrome i can only drag the big one :(

Comment: Right, because no where in your code are you adding ui-draggable (the .draggable directive) to the smaller bubbles. Your jQuery find will not grab those in its results. That is one issue. You still have another in there somewhere.

Comment: won't adding draggable to small ones allow to drag them separatly from the big one? I want small ones to be glued to the big ones.

Comment: Sounds like you want .draggable just on the container then.

Comment: hm... obviously I'm not to precise what I want to achieve. sorry. In the first edit add user1 and press big bubble then add user2 and press big bubble. You should have 2 big draggable bubbles. Type in a and press small buble, type b press small bubble type c and press small bubble. All the small ones should attach to the second big buble. When changing first input to hte name user1 you can add small bubbles in the same manner. Now both big bubbles should be draggable. Dragging should drag the propirate small ones. What I want to achieve is the ability to drag big and small start drag with smal

Comment: I understand your goal. There are errors in your code which do not conform to what you are stating as a goal (see updates above) and likely some additional, confounding issues.

Comment: I've made a new jsfiddle from scratch combining both what you said and what i need (http://jsfiddle.net/Sq4WJ/16/) and it turned out that it does work. One thing that was messing my "masterpiece" was z-index:-1 in the style. Obviously IE allow z-index:-1 and its ok while chrome stops seeing the object..... Thanks for helping me out :)